# please help me regarding backward compatibility of java1.8 with security features

Tags: java, ssl, encryption, java-8, java-security

I'm upgrading my application to **java1.8** - reason is some of our customers have started using **2048 bit encrypted** certificate. But I have two concerns , please help me with these queries:

**For incoming traffic:**

Will customers who are still with Java 1.7 and using 1024 bit encrypted certificate be able to connect to us? - I hope there should not be any backward compatibility issue with this . But still wanted to take suggestion from you guys .

**For outgoing traffic:**

will we be able to connect to customers who are still using 1024 bit encrypted key.

**One key point is :**

We have not upgraded our certificates or anything - only upgraded my jvm - that's it . Only those customers who are using 2048 bit encrypted key - we have stored their public key in our keystore so that they will be able to connect with us taking advantage of JDK1.8 in built support.

Answer (score 0):

If each customers has their own key, your application should be able to handle both 1024 and 2048 bit encryption. Anyway, test it just in case.